# Percorrer HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>>

Tags: java, hashmap

Tenho o seguinte `HashMap`:

```
HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>> hm = new HashMap<>();
```

Quando faço isto:

```
Set<Integer> keys = hm.keySet();
for(int i : keys) System.out.println(i + ": " +hm.get(i));
```

Tenho um output do género:

```
2: {2=[1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Como é que eu posso percorrer o `HashMap` principal, para ter acesso às chaves e valores do `HashMap` interior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deves de fazer separado, isto é percorrer o principal e por cada iteração percorrer o secundário.

*codigo:*

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer,HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>> kv: hm.entrySet()){
      //percorre map principal
      System.out.println("Key: "+kv.getKey()); //chave do principal
      //busca o map inferior dessa key 
      HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>> secondmap= kv.getValue();
      //percorre o map inferior
      for(Map.Entry<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>> kvv: secondmap.entrySet() ){
           //faz o print da chave e de todos os valores do arraylist
           for (int valor : kvv.getValue()){                               
                  System.out.println("Key: "+kvv.getKey() + "value "+valor;
           }

      }

}
```

Comment: Desde já Obrigado pela ajuda. dá-me logo erro na primeira linha do seu código: "Wrong number of type arguments: required: 2"

Comment: Este código não foi testado por nenhuma ide, logo deves ter alguma atenção ao código, erro no `etry` - fica `entry`

Comment: Sim já percebi isso e já corrigi. Penso que na primeira linha do seu código o 'HashMap' tem de sair e fica: 'for(Map.Entry<Integer,HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>> kv: hm.entryset()){'

Comment: @HugoMachado ve agora

Comment: Assim já funcionou ! Obrigado pela ajuda :D
Só mais uma questão depois, consigo percorrer no final o ultimo ArrayList?

Comment: `for (int valor : kvv.getValue()){
    System.out.println("arrayListvalores: "+ valor);
}`

Comment: Sim segue a mesma logica cria a lista, atribui a essa lista o valor do kvv.getvalue e depois é so percorrer

Comment: Vou Editar a pergunta e se me puder ver se tou a fazer algo errado agradecia.

Comment: @HugoMachado pus ai o código

Comment: Estava distraído não vi. Obrigado @JorgeB. funcionou ;)

Comment: @HugoMachado reverti a sua pergunta porque a "correção" que você colocou é a resposta que se encontra aqui.